# error executing an executable file made by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, executable

So, I made a software using python, the GUI is made with pyqt5, after wrapping everything with pyinstaller package i have an executable called Main.exe. When i execute the file normally it works, but i need to execute it with python code. i found this code which is usefull:

```
import os
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Project\dist\Main\Main.exe")
```

with other executable it works fine but whenever i try it with my executable 'Main.exe' it doesn't work. where is the problem coming from?

Comment: Does "it doesn't work" mean that nothing happens? Are you running the script from the prompt? Does it show any error message? Why do you need to run it from python?

Comment: @Jacobien: Are you sure the path is correct ? Shouldn't it look like this: `C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\Project\dist\Main\Main.exe`

Comment: @musicamante i need it to make auto-updates of my software, yes nothings happens, i just made a debug and it shows me Qapplication msut be constructed before qwidget. any solutions

Comment: @Maurice Meyer yes it's correct i did modify the path here on purpose

Comment: @Jacobien if you get that error, then there's probably something else wrong with your program. That said, the point about the update is not clear: is that code responsible of running the updater or restarting the program?

Comment: let me clarify it. when it's run manually or from the prompt the executabe works normal as it should be. but once i go to spyder and i use this 
```import os
os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Project\dist\Main\Main.exe") ```

it doesn't work anymore and it shows that error

Comment: the point of this one is to verify is the version of the software is the latest or not, if it is it executes 
```import os os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Project\dist\Main\Main.exe")```
if not, there is a script that will copy a Main.exe from a local repository and replace it with the actual one. and this is how i will update my software

Comment: If the `Main.exe` binary is self-contained (meaning that **everything** is in that exe), there should be no problem. But since you're reporting that QApplication issue, I'm afraid that there could be some problem depending on how your program is implemented. Are you **completely** sure that that executable works fine if put on another path (and, possibly, another computer/vm/env)? In any case, IDEs are known for untraceable issues (due to working paths) and errors especially when dealing with complex frameworks as Qt, have you tried to run that script in standalone mode from a command prompt?